# ui.router $state.go('state') redirecting to deafault page

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular and in web so have patience 
I have three pages a login page ,a home page, a quote page.
From login page you go to home page from there you to quote page I am using **ui.router** . For this transition from login to home is working fine but from home to quote its not working

here is my router.js

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($routeProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  $stateProvider.state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'views/login.html',
    controller:'appController'
  });
  
  $stateProvider.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
     templateUrl:'views/home.html',
        controller:'homeCtrl'
  });
  
  $stateProvider.state('quote',{
     url:'/quote',
     templateUrl:'views/quote.html',
        
  });
    
}]);
```

and here is my controler.js

```js
app.controller("appController",['$scope','$http','$state','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$state,$rootScope){
  // console.log("here");
   var config = {
              'Content-Type':'text/plain'
            };

 $scope.authenticate= function(user) {

$state.go('home');
    };
}]);

app.controller("homeCtrl",[
    '$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){
        
        $scope.categories=["inspirational","love","family","life","war","patriotism"];
        $scope.selectedCategory=function(category) {
         //   alert(category);
           $state.go('quote');
        };           
    }]);
```

Comment: You should remove `$routeProvider` from your dependencies in `app.config`

Comment: @melix just redirecting to quote so far so don't need a controller yet

Comment: @henrikmerlander removed that stil not working it was there because i was working on it earlier

Comment: Yeah i know that's why I did not post it as an answer. Can you show how your quote.html looks? Maybe there is some error in the console when you try to do the transition?

Comment: its just a plain static html @henrikmerlander

Answer (score 0):

You config wrong ui-router state it should be a chain....and check `$scope.selectedCategory` function works.. Hope it works.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($routeProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
       $stateProvider
         .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl:'views/login.html',
            controller:'appController'
          })
         .state('home',{
            url:'/home',
             templateUrl:'views/home.html',
                controller:'homeCtrl'
          })
          .state('quote',{
             url:'/quote',
             templateUrl:'views/quote.html'

          });

}]);
```

Comment: Tried that not working $sate.go('quote') is working fine in appcontroller but its redirecting to index when used in homectrl... some its redirecting to quote some times it don't

Comment: You have no 'index' defined anywhere. What do you mean by redirect to index?

Comment: I meant the default page that is in this case is login @henrikmerlander